# gson view unable to resolve domain class

Tags: grails, grails-3.3

I'm using grails 3.3.0 with rest api and gson views. I have the following setup...

**Domain Class**

```
package foo

@Resource(uri="/api/bars", readOnly = false, formats = ['json', 'xml'])
class Bar{
    String firstName
    String lastName
}
```

**Controller:**

```
package foo

class BarController extends RestfulController<Building>{

    def show(){
        respond Bar.get(params.id)
    }
}
```

**_bar.gson:**

```
import foo.Bar;

model {
    Bar bar
}

json {
    name bar.firstName
}
```

**_show.gson:**

```
import foo.Bar;

model {
    Bar bar
}

json g.render(template:"bar", model:[bar:bar])
```

**directory layout:**

```
/grails-app/views/
-----------------bar/
--------------------_bar.gson
--------------------_show.gson
```

This fails during `build`, `test`, `compile` and `war` with the following error:

```
Execution failed for task ':compileGsonViews'.
foo_bar_show_gson: 3: unable to resolve class foo.Bar
```

I followed the documentation but I cannot get around this.  Please help!

Comment: You'll have to create an example project. The class should definitely be on the classpath for view compilation if it is in `grails-app/domain`

Comment: This above example works with the 'web' profile and not the 'rest' profile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking through github issues this seems to be caused by the `rest` profile and running on a Windows machine. If I start a new project using the `web` profile everything works fine.

Comment: I was facing the same issue. I tried to run application using gradle build and build fialed at gsonViewCompile. I ran it with grails run-app and it ran without any error. So this points to a fact that it is an issue with gradle version because compilation failes with gradle clean build but works fine with ./gradlew clean build (a gradle wrapper supplied along with project)

Answer (score 5):

I have the same issue, my problem got solved when I change the views-gradle version to the 1.2.7

```
classpath "org.grails.plugins:views-gradle:1.2.7"
```